# How to add images in layout in multiple rows?

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I want to show some images in multiple rows. Please see the image below:
[image]

You can see this is not in tabular form. Please suggest how can I show the images in this manner. All images are coming from API.

**What I did so far:** 
I have created a `LinearLayout` dynamically and adding images in layout but it is showing in single row only.

Comment: Well, if your LinearLayout has horizontal orientation, there will only one row. You can use GridLayout.

Comment: Can we show this type arrangements of Images.. Please confirm